# Accessing CakePHP $this in a custom class

Tags: php, cakephp

I have my own class `foo` in `/src/Utility/foo.php` which can be accessed in any CakePHP script as long I add `use App\Utility\foo;` - that far this works.

There is usually not a problem to pass to a PHP constructor the `$this` object of the caller instance.

In order to get the exactly instance name of `$this` I retrieved it in the constructor of my class using `get_class($this)`.
This returns `AdminLTE\View\AdminLTEView`

- I instantiate my custom class with `$fooInstance = new foo($this);`.
- The constructor of my class looks like this:
  `public function __construct(AdminLTE\View\AdminLTEView $appThis)`

Using the above syntax results in this error:

> Argument 1 passed to App\Utility\foo::__construct() must be an
> instance of App\Utility\AdminLTE\View\AdminLTEView, instance of
> AdminLTE\View\AdminLTEView given

When I don't set in the constructor the type of `$this` I receive the below CakePHP error message trying this command:
`$appThis->request->getAttribute('identity');`:

> requestHelper could not be found.

OK, what did I misunderstand, what am I missing, how is the correct syntax so I can use `$this` of the caller class in my custom class?

Comment: `get_class()` returns an already resolved name (resolving happens at compile time), and resolved names have no leading backslash, _unresolved_ fully qualified names however always start with a backslash: `\AdminLTE\View\AdminLTEView` **https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rules.php**

Comment: @ndm Thx. This fixes the first error message but now I get the second CakePHP message `requestHelper could not be found.`. It looks like `$appThis` isn't recognized correctly and the methods/members aren't found correctly.

Comment: `View::$request` is a protected property, you cannot access is out of the view class' scope, you'll have to use its public `getRequest()` method instead. Accessing undefined properties will cause the view's magic helper loader to kick in, so that you can for example do `$this->Html` in your view/template in order to trigger lazy loading of the respective helper matching that name, ie `HtmlHelper`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_class()` returns an already resolved name (resolving happens at compile time), and resolved names have no leading backslash, *unresolved* fully qualified names however always start with a backslash:

```
\AdminLTE\View\AdminLTEView
```

**https://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rules.php**

`View::$request` is a protected property, you cannot access is out of the view class' scope, you'll have to use its public `getRequest()` method instead:

```
$appThis->getRequest()->getAttribute('identity');
```

Accessing undefined properties will cause the view's magic helper loader to kick in, so that you can for example do `$this->Html` in your view/template in order to trigger lazy loading of the respective helper matching that name, ie `HtmlHelper`.